# Big-O complexity of n/1 + n/2 + n/3 +

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

Is the big O complexity of *n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n* O(nlogn) or O(n)? I want to know this for calculating all divisors of all numbers from 1 to n. My approach would be to go over all the numbers and marking their multiples. This would take the above-mentioned time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `n` multiplied with [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) sum which has logarithmic growth.

So `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that!